# PHP and CURL query and how to retrieve response in variable

Tags: php, curl

i am trying to use the CURL to get a respose back in a PHP web app..

```
curl -d "qid=QID&api_key=API_KEY&api_sig=API_SIG&time_stamp=TIMESTAMP" \
 http://api.1.com/v1.2/result/
```

I have all the variables as known - but how do i form and execute above in PHP to get the result into a $RESULTRESPONSE variable? I am expecting a response in xml format back.

I know of curl_init, curl_exec, but not sure how curl_setopt comes into play for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'YOU_URL_GOES_HERE');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
$YOUR_RETURN_EDCONTENT_GOES_HERE = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Not 100% sure what you mean, but this will store your information from the curl in the `$YOUR_RETURN_EDCONTENT_GOES_HERE` variable.

Comment: In above API example: curl -d "qid=QID&api_key=API_KEY&api_sig=API_SIG&time_stamp=TIMESTAMP" \
 http://api.1.com/v1.2/result/

Comment: Is the CURLOPT_URL == http://api.1.com/v1.2/result/qid=QID&api_key=API_KEY&api_sig=API_SIG&time_stamp=TIMESTAMP ??

Comment: Replace `'YOUURLGOESHERE'` with your url, yes. But I can't access that webpage. Are you sure it's correct?